# Cassandra /var/log/cassandra deleted by system after reboot

Tags: cassandra, nosql, devops

After install Cassandra by ansible in DebianOS, here is my /var/log/:

$ ls -ll /var/log/

'''
total 636
drwxr-xr-x  5 root      root         320 Oct  6 09:33 .

drwxr-xr-x 11 root      root        4096 Oct  1 01:08 ..

drwxr-xr-x  2 root      root         100 Oct  6 09:48 apt

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm        54315 Oct  6 09:52 auth.log

-rw-rw----  1 root      utmp           0 Oct  6 01:07 btmp

drwx------  2 cassandra cassandra    240 Oct  6 09:48 cassandra        <==========HERE========

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm       148418 Oct  6 09:52 daemon.log

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm          964 Oct  6 01:07 debug

-rw-r--r--  1 root      root        3532 Oct  6 09:48 dpkg.log

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm        34575 Oct  6 01:07 kern.log

-rw-rw-r--  1 root      utmp      296296 Oct  6 09:50 lastlog

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm        63877 Oct  6 09:48 messages

drwx------  2 root      root          40 Oct  6 01:07 private

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm       214245 Oct  6 09:52 syslog

-rw-r-----  1 root      adm        30504 Oct  6 09:48 user.log

-rw-rw-r--  1 root      utmp       70000 Oct  6 09:50 wtmp

'''

This time, after installation Cassandra cluster is up and running.
But after REBOOT /var/log/cassandra not available and cassandra have no permission to mkdir in/var/log and failed to start.

$ ls -ll /var/log/

'''
total 352
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm        1167 Oct  6 09:51 auth.log

-rw-rw---- 1 root     utmp          0 Oct  6 09:50 btmp

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm      114270 Oct  6 09:56 daemon.log

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm         964 Oct  6 09:50 debug

drwxr-x--- 2 influxdb influxdb     40 Oct  6 09:50 influxdb

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm       34619 Oct  6 09:50 kern.log

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     utmp     296296 Oct  6 09:50 lastlog

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm       35237 Oct  6 09:51 messages

drwx------ 2 root     root         40 Oct  6 09:50 private

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm      151361 Oct  6 09:56 syslog

-rw-r----- 1 root     adm        1820 Oct  6 09:51 user.log

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     utmp       2400 Oct  6 09:50 wtmp

'''

$ nodetool status
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/log/cassandra': Permission denied
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

I've tried so many times, but don't know why system deleted my cassandra log dir.

- try reinstall Cassandra [DIDNT WORK]
- create a service mkdir /var/log/cassandra at reboot time [DINDT WORK]

Please help me.